# Detecting swipe gesture iOS - Cordova/Phonegap Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, swipe

I am having trouble successfully detecting a swipe event on a non-native iOS app I'm making.

```
<div id="video" data-ng-click="adminSelectVideo(video)" ng-repeat="video in videos">
```

Could anyone help me with a javascript implementation of detecting a left swipe gesture on the following div element 'video'?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use [hammerjs](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) for javascript multitouch gestures. Swipe gesture is one of them

```
var element = document.getElementById('video');
Hammer(element).on("swipeleft", function() {
    console.log('you swiped left me!');
});
```